# MVVM Light 5.2 и страничная навигация

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, mvvm-light

Очередной вопрос по навигации в WPF. Пытаюсь использовать MVVM Light Toolkit 5.2. Итак, есть `MainWindow` и к нему `MainViewModel`. `MainWindow` Содержит две панельки и `Frame` (может быть `ContentControl`) для отображения остальных вьюшек. В приложении хочется сделать страничную навигацию, да, желательно, так, чтобы не лезть в code behind.

Поскольку решено пользовать MVVM Light Toolkit, мне подумалось что хорошо бы родить какой-нибудь `NavigationService`, который всё будет знать о вью и этими самыми вью будет рулить. Исходя из хотелок, родился вот такой монстр:

```
public interface INavigationService
{
    void NavigateTo(string pageKey);

    void RegisterView(string pageKey, Type page);
}

public abstract class NavigationServiceBase<T> : INavigationService
{
    private T _currentPage;

    public T CurrentPage { 
        get{
            return _currentPage;
        } 
    }

    private Dictionary<string,Type> _registeredPages;
    public virtual void NavigateTo(string pageKey){
        if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(pageKey))
            throw new ArgumentNullException("pageKey", "Value can not be null or empty");

        Type view;
        if(_registeredPages.TryGetValue(pageKey, out view))
            _currentPage = (T)Activator.CreateInstance(view);
    }

    public virtual void RegisterView(string pageKey, Type page)
    {
        if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(pageKey) || page == null) 
            throw new ArgumentNullException();

        _registeredPages.Add(pageKey, page);
    }
    public NavigationServiceBase ()
    {
    _registeredPages = new Dictionary<string, Type>();
    }
}

public class PageNavigationService : NavigationServiceBase<Page>{
    public PageNavigationService () : base()
    {

    }
}

public class ViewModelLocator{
        static ViewModelLocator(){
            ServiceLocator.SetLocatorProvider(() => SimpleIoc.Default);
            SimpleIoc.Default.Register<INavigationService>(() => CreateNavigationService());
        }

        private static INavigationService CreateNavigationService(){
            var navigationService = new PageNavigationService();
            navigationService.RegisterView("EmployeesView",typeof(EmployeesView));
            return navigationService;
        }
}
```

Однако, после рождения монстра, у меня возникли сомнения в правильности такого решения: предполагалось, что `NavigationService` будет инжектиться в основную `ViewModel` и "пробросит" туда свойство `CurrentPage`, на которое забиндится `Content` фрейма. Но, поскольку у INavigationService этого свойства нет и быть не может, смысл этого интерфейса теряется полностью, что не хорошо.

Итак, вопросы:

1. Есть ли способ внутри `NavigationService` получить каким-то образом ссылку на фрейм, не передавая ее через конструктор и не устанавливая свойств сервиса? Чтобы можно было внутри `NavigationService` выполнить `refToFrame.Content = Activator.CreateInstance(SomeView)`
2. Может быть я вообще не туда смотрю и лучше использовать какой-нибудь `Messenger` или другой механизм для этой цели?
3. Может быть лучше сделать `NavigationService` синглтоном и дергать его в нужную `ViewModel` по необходимости?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В общем, получилось реализовать задуманное с помощью **Мессенджера**.

Добавился класс `NavigateToMessage`

```
public class NavigateToMessage<T>()
{
 public T View {get; private set;}

 public NavigateToMessage(T view){
  View = view;
}
```

`NaviagtionServiceBase` не изменился. `PageNavigationService` Дополнился переопределенным методом `NavigateTo()`:

```
...
public override NavigateTo(string pageKey)
{
 base.NavigateTo(pageKey);
 Messenger.Default.Send(new NaviagteToMessage<Page>(_currentPage));
}
```

В главной `ViewModel` регистрируемся как получатель сообщения и устанавливаем свойство `CurrentPage`, которое биндится на **Content** фрейма в главном вью.

```
MessengerInstance.Register<NavigateToMessage<Page>>(this, message =>
{
 CurrentPage = message.View;
});
```

Надеюсь, что решение поможет кому-то ещё, кроме меня.